# modules which have faithful sub-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

An $R$-Module $M$ is faithful if $\{a \in R \mid\forall m\in M \space \space am=0\}=\{0\} \space($ i.e the annihilator of $M$ in $R$ is zero).
Is there a module $M$ which has a faithful submodule $N$ but $M$ not be faithful?

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is not faithful, then there is $a\in R$ with $a\neq 0$ such that $am=0$ for every $m\in M$. Since every submodule $N$ of $M$ is also a subset of $M$, this means that for every $n\in N$ $an=0$. Thus, $N$ cannot be faithful.

Comment: no, maybe I didn't explain it well. suppose that $N$ is a faithful submodule then dose it implies $M$ must be faithful?

Comment: Yes, this is what the answer essentially says: if $M$ is not faithful, then any submodule of $M$ is also not faithful. Hence, the contrapositive statement is that if $N\subseteq M$ and $N$ is faithful, then $M$ is faithful as well.